# Time series data visualization in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a sample `dataset` that I am trying to visualize `point` data for a selected based of a `slider`. But I am getting an error with `xts` which is as follows:

```
 Error in try.xts: must be either xts-coercible or timeBased
```

How can this error be fixed?

Sample data

```
Date= c("2014-04-08", "2014-06-04", "2014-04-30",
              "2014-05-30", "2014-05-01")
lat = as.numeric(c("45.53814", "45.51076", "45.43560", "45.54332",
        "45.52234"))
lon = as.numeric(c("-73.63672", "-73.61029", "-73.60100",
        "-73.56000 ", "-73.59022"))
id = as.numeric(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Code

```
# This is a Shiny time series map web application
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(leaflet)
library(xts)

# Create a df from the above columns
df = data.frame(id, lat, lon, Date)
df$Year = lubridate::year(df$Date)
df$Month = lubridate::month(df$Date, label = TRUE, abbr=FALSE)
df$Week = lubridate::week(df$Date)
df$Date = as.Date(df$Date)

ui = fluidPage(
    
    # Title
    titlePanel("Time Series Visiualization Map"),

    sidebarLayout(
        
        # Define the sidebar
        sidebarPanel(
            
            radioButtons(inputId = "Frequency",
                         label = " Select Timer Series Frequency",
                         choices = c("Week",
                                     "Month",
                                     "Year"),
                         selected = "Week",
                         inline = T),
            
            uiOutput("Time_Series_UI")
            ),
        mainPanel(
            leafletOutput("Time_Series_Map")),
    ))
    


# Define server logic required 
server = function(input, output) {
    
    # Render slider input depending on data frequency
    
    observe({
        All_Dates = unique(df$Start_Date)
        Filtered_Dates = All_Dates[xts::endpoints(
            All_Dates, on = input$Frequency)]
    
    output$Time_Series_UI = renderUI({
        sliderInput("Date", "Date:",
                    min = min(Filtered_Dates),
                    max = max(Filtered_Dates),
                    value = min(Filtered_Dates),
                    step = 1,
                    timeFormat = "%YYYY-%MM-%DD",
                    animate = T)
    })
    
    })
    
    # Filter data for the date selected
    Filtered_Data = reactive({
        req(input$Date)
        df[df$Date == input$Date]
    })
        
    
    # Create the leaflet map
    output$Time_Series_Map = renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(df) %>% 
            addTiles() %>% 
            setView(lat = 0, lng = 0, zoom = 2) 
    })
    
    # Create data markers for selected date
    observe({
        df$id = Filtered_Data()
        
        leafletProxy("Time_Series_Map", data = df) %>%
            addCircleMarkers(lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat, 
                             popup = ~id)
    })     
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The object you are trying to use `xts::endpoints` on is not recognized or can't be coerced  to `xts`. You could create an xts for `xts::endpoints` to work like this: `dfxts <- xts(df, order.by = as.Date(df$Date))`.

Comment: @tester, so I did `df_xts = xts(df, order.by = as.Date(df$Date))` and then `Filtered_Dates = df_xts[xts::endpoints(df_xts, on = input$Frequency)]`. So, now I am getting this error:  `Warning: Error in match.arg: 'arg' should be one of “years”, “quarters”, “months”, “weeks”, “days”, “hours”, “minutes”, “seconds”, “milliseconds”, “microseconds”, “ms”, “us”`. Should I post a new question?

Comment: If you change your radioButtons to `choices = c("weeks", "months", "years"), selected = "weeks"` the app will at least start.